# Need a regexp to match >N Hashtags in a block of text

Tags: sql, regex

I need a regexp which will match only if there are >15 Hashtags in a block of text.

The regexp I'm using to match the hashtags is -

```
r'(\B#\w*[a-zA-Z]+\w*)'
```

I want to set a minimum number of Hashtags present check for this, where min. = 15.

Answer (score 1):

If `(\B#\w*[a-zA-Z]+\w*)` matches a single hashtag, then `(\B#\w*[a-zA-Z]+\w*){15,}` should match if there are 15 or more hashtags.